# PHP XML throws error on Latin-1 encoding

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Just a small problem but I've noticed that if first line of my xml has `encoding="Latin-1"` then the php simplexml and dom will throw an error and refuse to import. I did a workaround in which I'd import the xml as a string and regex `encoding="Latin-1"` into `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` before loading into the object which then doesn't throw an error, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution to this? Preferably something internal to the dom object so I can just import from file name.

Comment: I believe your rewriting workaround is already the appropriate solution. The charset name has no "Latin-1" alias. http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets

Comment: I'm working with a very large data set that isn't always formatted perfectly so I might have to keep regexing a lot of different aliases, if there's a way to just suppress the unrecognizable encoding error and load the file anyway that'd be great. I haven't found out how/if possible yet.

Comment: The PHP interface to libxml only provides `LIBXML_NOWARNING`, which is no help here. And even if there were an option to suppress actual errors (I doubt it), it's not exposed in the PHP methods.

Comment: Oh, well, thanks, at least I can stop banging my head against the wall and start thinking about something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is the code for the workaround:

```
if ($xml_file_handle = fopen($xml_file_path, "r")) {
    $xml_data = fread($xml_file_handle, filesize($xml_file_path));
    fclose($file_handle);

    $xml_data = preg_replace("/encoding=\"Latin-1\"/i", "encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"", $xml_data);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml_data);

    // Do stuff with $dom
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use simple_xml and others php xml functions and classes, you encoding your xml in UTF-8, use utf8_encode(xmlstring). If you xml has a simple english string without special chars same ú, í, á, ü, etc, you use without reencoding, but if you have these chars o similar chars, you need encodig use utf8_encode

Comment: The error isn't the fact it's not UTF-8 encoded, it's that the xml is telling simple_xml that it's Latin-1 encoded and simple_xml can't recognize that encoding format.